# How to setup Sails.js routes to support pushstate with a SPA on the frontend

Tags: api, express, assets, sails.js, pushstate

How to setup SailsJS routes to support pushstate, but still be able to serve requests prefixed with `/api` along with serving static assets as well?

Using:

- Backbone 1.x with `pushState: true`
- Sails 0.10.x

Suggested solution from this [thread](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/871) is to use the `/*` wildcard and redirect all to the index view.

**/path/to/app/config/routes.js**

```
'/*': {
  view: 'index' 
}
```

The problem is that this will redirect everything to index. including static file assets, the express.static middleware doesn't seem to have an effect, this route is somehow taking precedence.

Also, this prefix below doesn't have any effect, since the route above takes precedence, however the prefix works if I just remove the wildcard i.e `'/': { view: 'index' }`

**/path/to/app/config/blueprint.js**

```
module.exports.blueprints = {
    ...
    prefix: '/api',
    ...
}
```

Obviously, this does not seem as a core SailsJS issue, but rather my minimal knowledge the expressjs router, since that's what sailsjs is using.

Theoretically, I could explicitly just list out all the assets prefixed routes and have a controller to serve all, since they are well known and static i.e.  `'/js*': { controller: 'AssetsController', action: 'serve'`, and so on for `'/styles*'`, `'/images*'`, `'/templates*'`, `'/fonts*'`, but I'm really hesitant on doing so, I'm hoping for a better practice solution.

Also that won't solve this routes `/api` problem with the wildcard `'/*'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're willing to use the [development version of Sails from GitHub](http://github.com/balderdashy/sails), you can use the [`skipRegex`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/Routes.md#skipregex) route option to let your wildcard route ignore API requests, and the [`skipAssets`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/Routes.md#skipassets) option to have it ignore asset URLs:

```
'/*' : {view: 'index', skipAssets: true, skipRegex: /^\/api\/.*$/}
```

Otherwise, you can create a controller to serve your view, and add the code to skip unintentionally-matched URLs in the action code:

```
// api/controllers/StaticController.js
module.exports = {
   index: function(req, res, next) {
      if (req.path.match(/\..*/g) || req.path.match(/^\/api\/.*$/)) {
         return next();
      }
      return res.view('index');
   }
}
```

Then in `/config/routes.js`:

```
'/*': 'StaticController.index'
```

......

Comment: Im on 0.10.0-rc4, so wth - Thank you your first suggestion is what i'm looking for.

Comment: just want to point out that the regexp pattern needs to start at `/`, so `skipRegex: /^\/api\/.*$/` - i edited your post. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I refer to index.html from public folder instead of views?

Comment: I edited to serve index file from public folder instead of views `return res.sendfile('public/dev/index.html');`

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your `config/404.js` file.

1. Remove the following:

   > ```
   >   res.status(result.status);
   >   res.render(viewFilePath, function (err) {
   >     // If the view doesn't exist, or an error occured, send json
   >     if (err) { return res.json(result, result.status); }
   >
   >     // Otherwise, serve the `views/404.*` page
   >
   >     res.render(viewFilePath);
   >   });
   > ```
2. Add this: `res.redirect("/");`

Cheers

Comment: This would disabled the 404 page across the board, even for /api routes that don't exist...

Comment: @ScottGress you are right, unless of course I check `req.wantsJSON` and I contract my font-end `/api` requests to request JSON all the time.

@tUrG0n your solution was close, except that I do not want to `redirect('/')` since that would modify the URL, instead I could just `return this.res.view('homepage')` at the top of the function, oh and in `sails 0.10.0-rc4` it seems the `config/404.js` is moved to `api/responses/notFound.js` but same logic.

However, overloading the `404` route seems a bit hacky, I think I am with @ScottGress answer as down the road, that would be the right way to do so.